# Wordpress Avada Theme Secondary Menu Align Center

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm using Wordpress Avada theme v.5.3 and I try to center my secondary menu (The one at the top where you can also show Contact or Social info if you want). I just have a menu that is actually align left and I can't figure it out how to center it. I tried different manipulations in the CSS but nothing work.

How to change the alignment of my menu from left to center?

**What I have (align left):**
[image: What I have (align left)]

**What I want (align center):**
[image: What I want (align center)]

Comment: Hi Jean, you have to present your code to get help. Hardly anyone will have this theme instaled, but if you show the CSS/HTML that's giving problems, it'll be a breeze to provide solutions. If you haven't, please check the guides [tour] and [ask].

Comment: i didn't see any code posted in your question

Comment: I closed the question as duplicate because there are dozens of possible duplicates... check this search query: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcss%5D+horizontal+align+center+is%3Aquestion